# Смена позиции элементов в html структуре при медиа-запросах

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть код

```
<header>
<div class="header__top"></div>
<div class="header__mid"></div>
<nav></nav>
<div class="header__bot"></div>
</header>
<section></section>
```

Как с помощью JQuery переместить элемент **nav** под елемент **header__top**, при расширении экрана меньшего **768px** ?

Comment: а зачем `jquery` если в `css` можно задать `media` и при нужном размере задать `position`

Comment: Не понял, как ? 
У элементов уже заданы позиции, получается так, что топ и мид занимают 100% ширины и имеют внутренние блоки.

Comment: У `Flexbox` имеется свойство `order`, с помощью него можно управлять порядком элементов на странице. Например: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uk8uuaw0/).

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но в этой ситуации обертка для флексов не подойдет, потому как много элементов имеют разное позиционирование. В примере указан простой пример, чтобы потом разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

Вот, должно сработать. Работает при загрузке страницы так и при изменения размеры страницы.

```
function windowSize(){
    if ($(window).width() <= '768'){
        $('nav').after('.header__top');
    } else {
        $('nav').after('.header__mid');
    }
}

$(window).on('load resize',windowSize);
```

> А еще лучше дайте вашей `nav` какое нибудь имя класса и используйте
>   его.

Comment: Спасибо ) Но этот скрипт только перемещает разово элемент, потом он остается там.